# When to use `getExecutionCode` and when `execute`?

Tags: animation-nodes

Reading the documentation and the source I couldn't understand when to use what so far.
When do you use the method `getExecutionCode` and when `execute`?

Comment: From which object do these methods come ? What do you want to achieve ? Be a little more precise and we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may know Animation Nodes creates a python script based on your node tree. So each node has to provide some code that goes this script.

The *execute* function is fairly easy to use and should be prefered when you have a static amount of sockets and when the execution code does not change when you change some properties of the node.

The *getExecutionCode* function is called every time the node tree is changed. So it can return different code depending on some sockets. Also it avoids the function call overhead which can be noticable when you execute a node thousands of times.

In general you can write most nodes in both functions, there is no clear separation when to use what. I suggest you start writing nodes using the *execute* function.

btw: the *getExecutionCode* function will be generated automatically based on the sockets if the node has a *execute* function.

I hope that helps a bit, feel free to ask more detailed questions about the code. But maybe it would be better to ask them on github, not sure...

Comment: Thanks, I need some time to process that. Maybe I post a topic on github later regarding to what I want. For the rest, I think it would be good for future purpose to have simple questions like this answered here.